# We can't paste Excel ranges because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to loop through column A in Worksheet1 and find the first cell which has a specified text "Oil Production". This cell is the first cell in the array I wish to copy to Worksheet2. This cell and the size of the array will change from time to time, hence the code I have used. I then paste it into cell B7 in Worksheet2 which will never change.

This is my formula. I get the error at line `ActiveSheet.Paste`

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
        If Cell.Value = "Oil Production" Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
            Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Range("B7").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing `ActiveSheet.Cells.Select` to `Cell.Select` will solve your immediate issue.  That said, this code is flawed on many levels: disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` for debugging would have allowed you to see your issue; looping over the entire column A is unnecessary and slow; use of `Select` is unnecessary, slow and fragile [see here on How](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/445425)

Comment: Thanks for link and comments

Answer (score -1):

resize the area:

```
Sub Test()
Dim MyRowCount As Long, MyColCount As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row) 'This make it poll the used data rather than the whole column
    If Cell.Value = "Oil Production" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        With Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).column))
            .Copy
            MyRowCount = .Rows.Count
            MyColCount = .Columns.Count
        End With
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B7").Resize(MyRowCount, MyColCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        'Do you need to flick back to Sheet1 after pasting?
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Also I took out a bunch of selects for you.

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

can be written as

```
Range("A1").PasteSpecial XLPasteAll
```

You can chop out most selects this way, you can see I have also done it with the Range you are copying

Comment: Just a follow up question. This code does not seem to work that well when there is no data in A1. Or when there are empty cells in the column. I get an error at line Range("B7").Resize(MyRowCount, MyColCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Comment: Just put an if MyRowCount <> 0 AND MyColCount <> 0 then before the paste and an End if after it, if those are not set to a positive value then there is obviously no data to paste.